# Angular ui-router : hidden parameters and browser navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working with AngularJS [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/) to navigate in my app. I am trying to achieve something a little bit "out of the box" with the `$stateParams` in one of my states.

### Explanation

The state is a quizz, with several questions in a row. It is defined like so:

```
$stateProvider
.state('myQuizz', {
   url:"/myQuizz/{title}",
   cache:false,
   params:{
     step: null
   },
   views: {
     'myQuizz-tab': {
       templateUrl: "myQuizz.html",
       controller: "myQuizzCtrl"
     }
   }
})
```

- The param `title` appears in the URL, and defines which quizz the user is currently taking. For instance: *myApp.com/myQuizz/history*.
- The param `step` controls which step of the quizz the user is in (i.e. which question, for example question 6 out of 10). By default, my controller sets it to 1, so that the quizz starts with the first question.

Inside the quizz controller, what happens is more or less the following:

```
$scope.submitAnswer = function(answer){
    if(isValid(answer, $stateParams.step)){ // If the answer was correct
        $stateParams.step = $stateParams.step + 1; // Increases step
        displayQuestion($stateParams.step); // Gets the next question in the quizz
    }
}
```

So everytime the user answers a question, it updates the $stateParams.step and refreshes the display so that the next question appears.

### What I am trying to do

Now what I would like to do is **navigate between steps using the browser's buttons, giving the user the possibility to go back.** Let's make an example :

- The user is in another state, let's say the quizz menu. `// state "menu"`
- The user opens a quizz.  `// state "myQuizz", step = 1, 1st question is displayed`
- They answer the first question correctly, the controller updates the $stateParams.step and displays the second question. `// step = 2, 2nd question is displayed`
- They want to go back to the first question, so they press the "back" button of their browser. `// step = 1, 1st question is displayed`

What happens now is: when they press the "back" button, they are taken to the previous state ("menu"). I suspect that it's because when the $stateParam.step is updated, it doesn't change the URL (since this parameter is hidden).

**If `$stateParams.step` was a normal parameter (not hidden), it would work** (I tested). But I don't want this parameter to appear in the URL, that's where the trick is.

### My question

My question is: **how can I enable browser navigation while only changing one hidden $stateParam in my state?**

### What I tried so far

- I tried to add

  `$state.go('myQuizz', {title: $stateParams.title, step: $stateParams.step+1});`

  in my controller so that the browser thinks I changed state. No success with that.
- I also tried to use `$state.transitionTo`, with the same result.
- Finally I tried to refresh the state with a $state.reload(). This doesn't work for 2 reasons : it reinitiates the quizz to the first step, and it reloads all the images (that I preload in the beginning of the quiz), so that wouldn't be a satisfactory approach.

Comment: I don't see any other way except adding it into address which you dont want. May be you can add it in some coded format using `btoa()`

Comment: Hi Ashish, I agree with you and after more than a day of research, I decided to add the "step" parameter into the URL. I had to code a few more security methods to ensure there was no cheating or misbehaviour in the navigation, but it seems to work just fine now. Thank you for your comment. :)